# How exactly can a 720P DLP print at a higher resolution than a 2k LCD?

Tags: sla, dlp, lcd-screen

I'm still confused on this. The Anycubic Photon Ultra is coming out soon, and it features an internal 720p Projector. The 720p resolution seems like a far cry from a 2k LCD (1280×720 vs. 2560x1440). Despite having 4x as many pixels, many articles are praising DLP as being much higher in resolution / detail. This is very counterintuitive... How can a DLP projector with less pixels produce a more detailed item than a 2k LED exposure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can a digital camera produce images several times the resolution of the sensor?  They *move the sensor* and overlay multiple exposures.  Optically or physically moving the DLP chip or its projected image can give a combined "image" from multiple scans anywhere from 2x to several times the linear resolution of the DLP itself.

Such a print might be slower than an LCD, because of multiple exposures for each layer, but it might also be faster, because the light source can be *far* brighter than can be used with an LCD without damaging the liquid crystals themselvs.